# Почему не происходит редирект через navigate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router

подскажите пожалуйста, почему не происходит редирект через Navigate, после того как произошла авторизация, что и является условием для срабатывания Navigate:

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Input from '../UI/Input';
import Input1 from '../UI/Input1';
import ButtonSubmit  from '../UI/ButtonSubmit'
import Link1 from '../UI/Link1'
import Add from '../UI/ADD+';
import api from '../API copy';
import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth';
import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContexts';
import { useContext } from 'react/cjs/react.development';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';


function SignIn() {
  const [context, setContext] = useContext(AuthContext);
  const auth = useAuth()

  const sendData = () => {
    api.login({
      "login": login,
      "password": password
    }).then((r) => {
      console.log(r) 
      setContext({
        isLoaded: true
      }) ? <Navigate replace to="AddnewPlayer"/> : <Navigate replace to="/signin" />
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log(e)
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть специальный хук для этого, он отличается от КОМПОНЕНТА Navigate , то есть Navigate сработает непосредственно при вазврате jsx, а если ты хочешь делать переадресацию внутри функции, то для этого есть useNavigate()

```html
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'

function SignIn() {
  const [context, setContext] = useContext(AuthContext);
  const auth = useAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const sendData = () => {
    api
      .login({
        login: login,
        password: password,
      })
      .then((r) => {
        console.log(r);
        setContext({
          isLoaded: true,
        })
          ? navigate('/AddnewPlayer')
          : navigate('/singin');
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };
}
```